# fetching individual running process Start-Time

Tags: android, linux, process, linux-kernel, runtime

I am using below code to get all currently running process's on an Android device.

```
// Get running processes
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

And I am also trying to use the below code to get all individual process start time in the Android Device from each individual pid- "process id" in the following file directory:"/proc/[PID]/stat" obtained from linux:

```
public static long getStartTime(final int pid) throws IOException {

final String path = ("/proc/" + pid + "/stat");
final String stat;
final String field2End = ") ";
final String fieldSep = " ";
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

 try {
        stat = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("******Stat******"+ stat);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

try {
        final String[] fields = stat.substring(stat.lastIndexOf(field2End)).split(fieldSep);
        final long processstartTime = .....;
        ...(change processstartTime from clock tick to seconds & return processstartTime value)...
}
}
```

I do need to get the process StartTime from the following Linux directory path:"/proc/pid/stat" for each individual running processes in an Android Device. At this point, when I debug the statement for the following Linux directory path:"/proc/[PID]/stat", in the following code line: `System.out.println("******Stat******"+ stat);`, I am getting the output debug as :

> ******Stat******642 (flipboard.app) S 2848 2848 0 0 -1 4194624 126020 0 1019 0 2441 632 0 0 20 0 101 0 7040346 1079652352 7233 4294967295 1 1 0 0 0 0 4612 0 38120 4294967295 0 0 17 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Furthermore, I do know that the start_time of the process is measure in clock ticks, hence to convert it to seconds, I will need to cal the following as "start_time/hertz".

Now the issue is, How Do I get the Running Process Start Time in "/proc/[PID]/stat"? Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loggin of individual process time can be done by this way:

```
public static long getStartTime(final int pid) throws
        IOException {
    final long SYSTEM_CLK_TCK= 100; //needed as value in /proc/[PID]/stat file driectory is in clock ticks,100 is used to convert clock ticks to secs
    final int fieldStartTime = 20; //column 20 of the /proc/[PID]/stat file driectory
try {
        System.out.println("******String path******"+ path);
        stat = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("******String stat******"+ stat);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
try {
        final String[] fields = stat.substring(stat.lastIndexOf(field2End)).split(fieldSep);
        final long startTime = Long.parseLong(fields[fieldStartTime]);
        System.out.println("******fieldstarttime based on clock ticks******"+ startTime);

        return startTime * msInSec / SYSTEM_CLK_TCK;
}
```